# webrtc ontrack event handler not firing in async function

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, webrtc

I am trying to understand webRTC flow by writing a simple local rtc communication. I am also trying to write the code using the async/await syntax, I tried using Promises and its working perfectly. I have the following script tag in my `index.html` file

```html
<script async src="test.js" onload="init()"> </script>
```

and my javascript code

```js
const a = new RTCPeerConnection();
const b = new RTCPeerConnection();

async function init() {
    try {
        a.onicecandidate = e => {
            console.log("alice candidate ", e);
            if (e.candidate) {
                b.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
            }
        }
        b.onicecandidate = e => {
            console.log("bob candidate", e);
            if (e.candidate) {
                a.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

            }
        }
        let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: { width: 800, height: 600 }

        })
        document.getElementById("local").srcObject = stream;

        for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
            a.addTrack(track, stream);
        }

        let offer = await a.createOffer();
        await a.setLocalDescription(offer);
        await b.setRemoteDescription(a.localDescription);
        let answer = await b.createAnswer();
        await b.setLocalDescription(answer);
        await a.setRemoteDescription(b.localDescription);

        //my misunderstanding is here
        b.ontrack = async e => {
            console.log("test on track");
            document.getElementById("remote").srcObject = e.streams[0];
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.err(err);
    }
}
```

My problem comes when I try to put the ontrack event inside the async function. The ontrack event is never fired.

```js
//when I put this event outside the async function the code works but not inside
b.ontrack = async e => {
    console.log("test on track");
    document.getElementById("remote").srcObject = e.streams[0];
}
```

I don't know if it is bad practice but I prefer the async/await syntax rather than the `.then`. However as far as I know I can not write async/await outside an async function. So my question is why does then ontrack event do not fire inside the `async init()` function but it does work when I put it outside in the top level scope.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ontrack fires as part of setRemoteDescription. However, in your async code you are only adding a ontrack handler later so it won't get triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. I added the event handler before the setRemoteDescription and its working perfectly now ! One question, while I am reading the mozilla documentation for webRTC I can not seem to find this information where the ontrack fires as part of setRemoteDescription. Is my method to create my events bad ?

Comment: its deeply hidden in https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#set-the-rtcsessiondescription